# how to close module in android studio of a project ? how to reopen it?

Tags: android, android-studio

**want to close one module of a project for now and as there is no requirement for
a time period but after want to open that module again.**

is there such a functionality in android studio **EXCEPT MANUAL WAY** ?

ex : there is functionality in Eclipse to close project similarly want to close
        module in android studio.

Comment: What does "close" mean to you? You can just minimize the file tree to effectively hide it.

Comment: close means it should not show on search from anywhere in project @JasonRobinson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option of opening and closing a module in Android Studio. 
You can have multiple IDE windows open at once. Have the project with the library publish to a local Maven repo that the app pulls the artifact from.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio,switch the project navigator to Android.Right click the module,click the `Open Module Settings`.
[open module settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40WjQ.png)
Select the module you want to remove,and click red `-` ,now you removed the module.
[remove the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGabt.png)

To reopen the module,click `File` in menu,and click `New`->`Import Module`,find the folder where the moudle is,and import it.

Comment: that is manualway of doing. i know this way of doing. do you know way as in eclipse ? @Lewis Luo

Comment: As I known,no.@AmitVaghela

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to close the module, just right click the project -> Open Modules Settings, Select module in the left side, click "-". You maybe delete it in local project director also and check in Gradle for sure it is deleted. It will be deleted
2. If you want open it Again, File - Import Module - Browse to Module in local directory, it will be showed in Explorer project view, then Right click Project - Open Module Settings, Dependencies - find module and select it.

Hope you lucky